# awk OFS, getting unexpected results

Tags: csv, awk

I can't see why I am getting unexpected result here, if someone could bring
some light on this:-

Those are the first 5 records of `uk-500.csv` input file:

```
"first_name","last_name","company_name","address","city","county","postal","phone1","phone2","email","web"
"Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14 Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk"
"Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5 Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk"
"France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk"
"Ulysses","Mcwalters","Mcmahan, Ben L","505 Exeter Rd","Hawerby cum Beesby","Lincolnshire","DN36 5RP","01912-771311","01302-601380","ulysses@hotmail.com","http://www.mcmahanbenl.co.uk"
```

When I run this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\",?\"?"; OFS="=" } NR < 5 { print $3 }' uk-500.csv
```

I get:

```
last_name
Tomkiewicz
Zigomalas
Andrade
```

If I use:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\",?\"?"; OFS="=" } NR < 5 { printf $3" " }' uk-500.csv
```

I get:

```
last_name Tomkiewicz Zigomalas Andrade
```

Why in both cases `awk` ignores `OFS` value, shouldn't I get:

```
=last_name=Tomkiewicz=Zigomalas=Andrade=
```

**ADDITION**

While we are at a topic, it is worthwhile mentioning that in case of changing
`FS` and `OFS`, one would expect for plain `print` or `print $0` to output all
fields with recalculated values per record, however this wont happen because
no field was changed, so this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\",?\"?"; OFS="=" } NR < 5 { print }' uk-500.csv
```

will yield this:

```
"first_name","last_name","company_name","address","city","county","postal","phone1","phone2","email","web"
"Aleshia","Tomkiewicz","Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc","14 Taylor St","St. Stephens Ward","Kent","CT2 7PP","01835-703597","01944-369967","atomkiewicz@hotmail.com","http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk"
"Evan","Zigomalas","Cap Gemini America","5 Binney St","Abbey Ward","Buckinghamshire","HP11 2AX","01937-864715","01714-737668","evan.zigomalas@gmail.com","http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk"
"France","Andrade","Elliott, John W Esq","8 Moor Place","East Southbourne and Tuckton W","Bournemouth","BH6 3BE","01347-368222","01935-821636","france.andrade@hotmail.com","http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk"
```

The proper way of doing this would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\",?\"?"; OFS="=" } NR < 5 { $1=$1; print }' uk-500.csv
```

Now the result is like we expected:

```
=first_name=last_name=company_name=address=city=county=postal=phone1=phone2=email=web=
=Aleshia=Tomkiewicz=Alan D Rosenburg Cpa Pc=14 Taylor St=St. Stephens Ward=Kent=CT2 7PP=01835-703597=01944-369967=atomkiewicz@hotmail.com=http://www.alandrosenburgcpapc.co.uk=
=Evan=Zigomalas=Cap Gemini America=5 Binney St=Abbey Ward=Buckinghamshire=HP11 2AX=01937-864715=01714-737668=evan.zigomalas@gmail.com=http://www.capgeminiamerica.co.uk=
=France=Andrade=Elliott, John W Esq=8 Moor Place=East Southbourne and Tuckton W=Bournemouth=BH6 3BE=01347-368222=01935-821636=france.andrade@hotmail.com=http://www.elliottjohnwesq.co.uk=
```

Comment: You're only printing a single field. Try `print $1,$2,$3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OFS` stands for Output Field Separator. By default that is set to single space. When you use `printf`, `OFS` is never used.

What you are probably looking for is `ORS` which is Output Record Separator which by default is set to newline.

Setting the `ORS` will give you the following output.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="\",?\"?"; ORS="=" } NR < 5 { print $3 }' uk-500.csv
last_name=Tomkiewicz=Zigomalas=Andrade=
```

You can use `END` block if newline is important.